# Java AnnotationProcessing - Get fields of the Annotation

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

I have a question according to the API AnnotationProcessing.
Here's a little Example.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface MyAnnotation
{
   String strNumberOne() default "";

   String strNumberTwo() default "";

   String strNumberThree() default "";
}


public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv){
    // I do not know how to beginn here
      return true;
   }
}

public class MyClass
{
   @MyAnnotation(strNumberOne="one", strNumberTwo= "two")
   private String strARandomString;
}
```

Now I want to read the fields declared in the annotation and if there's a field not declared my program should take the default-value.

I want to write the values in a list. At the end my list shoud look like that:

```
LinkedList<String> s = new LinkedList<>();
s.add(strNumberOne); // "one"
s.add(strNumberTwo); // "two"
s.add(strNumberThree); // (default) ""
```

How do I do this? I found a method that could help. It's in the Interface "Elements" the methods name is "getElementValuesWithDefaults()". But I don't know how to use it..
Also I want to know what's the difference betweens TypeElement and Element.
I am thankful for every answer! :)

Best regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `MyAnnotation` is the annotation which your processor supports, then you'd just write something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
                       RoundEnvironment           env) {
    if (shouldClaim(annotations)) {
        for (Element e : env.getElementsAnnotatedWith(MyAnnotation.class)) {
            MyAnnotation a = e.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);

            String str1 = a.strNumberOne();
            String str2 = a.strNumberTwo();
            String str3 = a.strNumberThree();
            // Add them to a List or whatever you need.
        }

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean shouldClaim(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations) {
    Set<String> supported = getSupportedAnnotationTypes();
    for (TypeElement a : annotations) {
        if (supported.contains(a.getQualifiedName().toString()))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The logic of the `shouldClaim` method is explained by the documentation for [`process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html#process-java.util.Set-javax.annotation.processing.RoundEnvironment-). It would be more complicated if your annotation supports e.g. `*` or a type of the form `name.*`, but in general you don't. (See [`getSupportedAnnotationTypes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html#getSupportedAnnotationTypes--) for a description of what those mean.)

If `MyAnnotation` *isn't* the annotation which your processor supports, then you *would* need to go through `getElementValuesWithDefaults` *if* it's a type declared in the package you're compiling. Because annotation processing happens *during* compilation, class files don't exist yet for the source files being compiled, which is why we use the `Element` API instead.

`Element` represents a declaration of some kind, for example a class, method or variable. `TypeElement` represents a class, interface, enum or annotation type declaration. `TypeElement` is similar to `Class` in terms of what we can do with it, except that we can use a `TypeElement` for a class which is not necessarily compiled.

To get annotation values through the element API, you'd do something like this:

```
Elements    elements     = processingEnv.getElementUtils();
TypeElement myAnnotation = elements.getTypeElement("com.example.MyAnnotation");

for (Element e : env.getElementsAnnotatedWith(myAnnotation)) {
    for (AnnotationMirror mirror : e.getAnnotationMirrors()) {
        DeclaredType annotationType = mirror.getAnnotationType();
        Element      annotationDecl = annotationType.asElement();

        if (myAnnotation.equals(annotationDecl)) {
            Map<? extends ExecutableElement, ? extends AnnotationValue> values =
                elements.getAnnotationValuesWithDefaults(mirror);

            String str1 = (String) getValue(values, "strNumberOne");
            String str2 = (String) getValue(values, "strNumberTwo");
            String str3 = (String) getValue(values, "strNumberThree");
            // ...
        }
    }
}

private Object getValue(Map<? extends ExecutableElement,
                            ? extends AnnotationValue> values,
                        String name) {
    for (Map.Entry<? extends ExecutableElement,
                   ? extends AnnotationValue> e : values.entrySet()) {
        if (name.contentEquals(e.getKey().getSimpleName()))
            return e.getValue().getValue();
    }
    return null;
}
```

That's a pain, but we only need to use the element API *if* the annotation we're interested in is one of the classes being compiled.

We might also want to find the `AnnotationMirror` and/or `AnnotationValue` to cause a message of some kind on a particular element using one of the [`Messager.printMessage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Messager.html#printMessage-javax.tools.Diagnostic.Kind-java.lang.CharSequence-javax.lang.model.element.Element-javax.lang.model.element.AnnotationMirror-) overloads which takes one of the aforementioned objects as an argument.